# Light CMS that does not require a database

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I am looking for a light CMS that I can use for creating a simple personal website for a friend. The server that he will host his website only supports PHP and no databases.

So, I need a CMS that may not be very scalable but the important thing is that it must be easy to use with a simple user interface that a layman can use to add content (and as I said no databases).

Comment: A simple Google search would have been helpful: https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cms+no+database. You might try PivotX, gpEasy, editease -- it all depends what you want and what is available.

Comment: @Matt Thanks. And sorry I googled but probably with wrong keywords and came across Symphony and Silva . :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FlatPress](http://flatpress.org/home/) is a blogging engine which stores its entries in flat files instead of a database.  I've used it for a couple small private blogs for a couple years and liked it.  I expect that with some customization you can make it look less blog-like.

Answer (score 0):

What about PageLime: http://pagelime.com/

Its pure HTML but has an interface to editting an publishing through web and mobile devices.

Plus, you can have up to 3 sites for free.

Comment: sorry. But, I was looking for some open-source stuff that I can run on my server.

Comment: No prob. I'll leave the tip.

Answer (score 0):

[dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) is a php based wiki that does not require a database.  I think you could use it as a simple CMS.